# How to read raw text from .txt file using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

My text file has values like this:

```
00001
00002
00003
```

The `pandas.read_csv` function reads the values as `1, 2, 3`. I want them to be read in raw format as `00001` etc.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### [`converters`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

The key `0` in the dictionary `{0: str}` refers to either the column name or position.  In this case, it is both.

```
pd.read_csv('tst.csv', header=None, converters={0: str})

       0
0  00001
1  00002
2  00003
```